# Can't DeserializeObject with NewtonsoftJson an Unknown Properties' Type

Tags: json, .net, class

I'm getting the following JSON as a string:

```
{
  "3-7-14days": [
    {
      "Column0": null,
      "Column1": "Updated on",
      "Column2": "16_Jul_2020",
      "Column3": null
    },
    {
      "Column0": null,
      "Column1": 12.535,
      "Column2": null,
      "Column3": "ABC"
    }
  ],
  "1-3-12months": [
    {
      "Column0": null,
      "Column1": 1.3809423719058225,
      "Column2": 1.212719793382322,
      "Column3": 1.1911422696591887
    },
    {
      "Column0": null,
      "Column1": "JPM",
      "Column2": "AMAT",
      "Column3": "UNM"
    }
  ],
  "explanation": []
}
```

The structure will always be

1. "3-7-14days" array (unknown size) of 4 columns (I don't know if the columns are strings, numbers, or nulls)
2. "1-3-12months" array (unknown size) of 4 columns (I don't know if the columns are strings, numbers, or nulls)
3. empty array called "explanation".

I couldn't build a class for this object since the type of the properties is unknown.
I even tried the following code just to get the explanation array, and it didn't work.

```
var jsonExplanation = new { explanation = "" };
var explanationArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(itemresultJson, jsontest);
```

The final result should be an object of this JSON.
Any idea?

Comment: Use `JObject.Parse` and then split the property names however you want into whatever structure you want.

Comment: You could do JObject.Parse and inspect the properties one by one